# import error while bundling using py2exe

Tags: python

I bundled a small script written in python using py2exe. The script uses many packages and one of them is  reportlab. 
After bundling using py2exe  I tried to run the executable file and it is returning following error:

```
C:\Python26\dist>DELchek.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "DELchek.py", line 12, in <module>
File "reportlab\pdfgen\canvas.pyc", line 25, in <
File "reportlab\pdfbase\pdfdoc.pyc", line 22, in
File "reportlab\pdfbase\pdfmetrics.pyc", line 23,
File "reportlab\pdfbase\_fontdata.pyc", line 158,
ImportError: No module named _fontdata_enc_winansi
```

But I could see the '_fontdata_enc_winansi' module in reportlab folder. Could someone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 13):

I've had the same problem in the past bundling reportlab with py2exe. It imports of a bunch of modules dynamically, which py2exe does not recognize when assembling the dependencies.  The brute-force fix is to import the required modules directly in your code:

```
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_winansi
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_macroman
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_standard
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_symbol
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_zapfdingbats
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_pdfdoc
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_enc_macexpert
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_courier
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_courierbold
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_courieroblique
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_courierboldoblique
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_helvetica
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_helveticabold
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_helveticaoblique
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_helveticaboldoblique
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_timesroman
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_timesbold
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_timesitalic
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_timesbolditalic
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_symbol
from reportlab.pdfbase import _fontdata_widths_zapfdingbats
```

A search also shows that Sankar found [another solution](http://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-list/2011-July/1277251.html), which is including the following packages in the setup script:

```
packages=[
    'reportlab',
    'reportlab.graphics.charts',
    'reportlab.graphics.samples',
    'reportlab.graphics.widgets',
    'reportlab.graphics.barcode',
    'reportlab.graphics',
    'reportlab.lib',
    'reportlab.pdfbase',
    'reportlab.pdfgen',
    'reportlab.platypus',
],
```

Comment: This also solved my problem with pyinstaller when importing PISA

Answer (score 2):

Skip graphics if you are not using them...

```
packages= [
    'reportlab',
    'reportlab.lib',
    'reportlab.pdfbase',
    'reportlab.pdfgen',
    'reportlab.platypus',
]

setup(name='pitman',
    version='1.0',
    author='cue',
    data_files = dataFiles,
    console=['xxx.py', 'yyy.py'],      # change to windows=[...]
    options = {
        "py2exe": { "dll_excludes": ["MSVCP90.dll"],
                    "packages": packages,
                    "includes": includes }
                  }
  )
```