# Unable to use the socket library in webapp2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sockets, webapp2

For some reason I'm unable to use the socket library completely in webapp2.
On printing the dir contents of the library, I get the following:

```
[
 'AF_INET', 'SOCK_DGRAM', 'SOCK_STREAM', '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT',
 '__all__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__',
 '__package__', '_fileobject', 'error', 'gaierror', 'getdefaulttimeout',
 'herror', 'setdefaulttimeout', 'ssl', 'timeout'
]
```

As you can see, this is not the complete socket library(it also lacks the socket() constructor). Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using webapp2 on appengine? Using sockets in appengine is not allowed. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Sandbox

Comment: You may be interested in this App Engine Trusted Testers program: https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/9b5c7ab0386ac75a/55fd1147fe9e2d5c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because opening a socket is [explicitly forbidden](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Sandbox) in AppEngine.

Comment: I looked for that before posting the question. But I found other code snippets on stackoverflow using sockets. Eg:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274596/import-error-when-building-python-using-py2exe
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470733/how-can-i-handle-static-files-with-python-webapp2-in-heroku

Comment: Never mind. I didn't realize the difference between webapp2 and appengine. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Good news! Google recently released a sockets API for app engine, documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/

It is still in a preview release (as of Mar. 2014) and it comes with its own host of limitations, but it should be able to handle many situations.