# PyInstaller generated exe not working, project uses ReportLab

Tags: python, pyside, reportlab, pyinstaller

I'm trying to generate an exe for my project. It worked without problems about a month back when my project didn't use ReportLab, but now, not so much.

After searching through, I found that the problem was [a missing import](http://www.pyinstaller.org/ticket/651) in one of the pyinstaller files. 
Problem Solved right? Not exactly.

Now I get this error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 386, in importHook 
mod = _self_doimport(nm, ctx, fqname)
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\myproject\build\pyi.win32\myproject\out00-PYZ.pyz\reports.My_Report_File", line 10, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 431, in importHook
mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, ctx + '.' + nm)
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\myproject\build\pyi.win32\myproject\out00-PYZ.pyz\reportlab.pdfgen.canvas", line 25, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 431, in importHook
mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, ctx + '.' + nm)
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\myproject\build\pyi.win32\myproject\out00-PYZ.pyz\reportlab.pdfbase.pdfdoc", line 22, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 431, in importHook
mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, ctx + '.' + nm)
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\myproject\build\pyi.win32\myproject\out00-PYZ.pyz\reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics", line 23, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 431, in importHook
mod = self.doimport(nm, ctx, ctx + '.' + nm)
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 480, in doimport
exec co in mod.__dict__
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\myproject\build\pyi.win32\myproject\out00-PYZ.pyz\reportlab.pdfbase._fontdata", line 158, in <module>
File "F:\Python\pyinstaller-2.0\pyinstaller-2.0\PyInstaller\loader\iu.py", line 409, in importHook
raise ImportError("No module named %s" % fqname)
ImportError: No module named _fontdata_enc_winansi
```

Searching around, I found [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pyinstaller/pZ4UX94qdb0/G3rbQ4Eqg1sJ) leading to only one proposed solution which was to force all the imports in my code files. I have way too many report files making it difficult for me to even think about doing that.

I read something about hidden imports. Maybe that may help me out, but I don't know. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786473/import-error-while-bundling-using-py2exe) problem and solution for py2exe....

Comment: Looks like this question has already been addressed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6786473/import-error-while-bundling-using-py2exe

Comment: @MikeVella that link is for py2exe. I don't understand how this helps me. I've mentioned the link in the question though.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion by robots.jpg in that answer? What happened when you did?

Comment: @MikeVella i inserted the packages list in my spec file and generated from that, same error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if I this is the proper way to do it... but I'm starting to pull my hair out.

After reading around and wasting a bunch of time, ...

I found a post by someone which suggests **copying the whole missing library folder** (in my case it was in site-packages of my pythonxx) **into the folder containing the exe**. Walla! It worked.

If there is a better/proper way to do this, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1):

Add a file named `hook-reportlab.pdfbase._fontdata.py` to the hooks subdirectory of pyinstaller. The conten should read like this:

```
hiddenimports = [
    '_fontdata_enc_macexpert',
    '_fontdata_enc_macroman',
    '_fontdata_enc_pdfdoc',
    '_fontdata_enc_standard',
    '_fontdata_enc_symbol',
    '_fontdata_enc_winansi',
    '_fontdata_enc_zapfdingbats',
    '_fontdata_widths_courier',
    '_fontdata_widths_courierbold',
    '_fontdata_widths_courierboldoblique',
    '_fontdata_widths_courieroblique',
    '_fontdata_widths_helvetica',
    '_fontdata_widths_helveticabold',
    '_fontdata_widths_helveticaboldoblique',
    '_fontdata_widths_helveticaoblique',
    '_fontdata_widths_symbol',
    '_fontdata_widths_timesbold',
    '_fontdata_widths_timesbolditalic',
    '_fontdata_widths_timesitalic',
    '_fontdata_widths_timesroman',
    '_fontdata_widths_zapfdingbats']
```

This worked for me with pyinstaller 2.1. BTW, I borrowed this file from pyinstaller 1.5.1 where it was installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I was on my own project, using reportlab and tkinter, I'm not expert at systems and either in python but I found that we can use the next code to import all the data: https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-pyinstaller/

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --add-data "C:/Desktop/M_Cat_Loaf.jpeg;." mypythonfile.py
```

where `add data` insert all your data files that you need (for example a cutie cat picture), I don't know what `nonconsole` do but it inserted to the folder all a needed :D

Hope it helps!